# Is it safe for the default NEAR TLA to have a FullAccess key?

Tags: nearprotocol

I noticed that the `near` top level account on NEAR MainNet has got this access key associated with it:

```
{
  "public_key": "ed25519:5zset1JX4qp4PcR3N9KDSY6ATdgkrbBW5wFBGWC4ZjnU",
  "access_key": {
    "nonce": 1568,
    "permission": "FullAccess"
  }
}
```

This key is hard-coded [in the genesis](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/c116d83a7d6b1dfeb392dcfbba4ddcefdc9f0957/neard/res/mainnet_genesis.json#L760).

From what I understand, this effectively means that an entity in possession of the corresponding private key may at any time delete any account that has its ID ending with `.near`, transferring all funds from that account wherever they choose. This includes all accounts created via the official NEAR [web wallet](https://wallet.near.org/) or by otherwise calling `near.create_account()`.

I'd like to know if my understanding is correct, whether this is absolutely required for the network to function or not, and what security implications this might have for a typical user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you cannot affect a subaccount from the parent like this. If someone deletes the `near` account, your account would not be affected. and unless the `near` account itself is holding a `FullAccess` key to subaccounts, it doesn't control them

This would also be easy to test. On TestNet try creating a subaccount and deleting it from the parent. If you don't have a `FullAccess` key to an account then your `DeleteAccount` action will be rejected by the network.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry for not testing beforehand.

Comment: absolutely no worries @ashpool, lots to learn. keep the questions coming